# Ordering results in JSON variable by integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am building a jQuery search suggestion script based upon two Google API's. Each API outputs a "relevance" integer (which I am returning next to each item to demonstrate) and I want to be able to order the results by that integer for each item.

**How can I do this?** I tried making the script output everything into one variable but I couldn't quite work it out.

A working demo can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/rEPf3/

My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q="+$("#search").val()+"&client=chrome&callback=?",function(data){
            var suggestion="";
            for(var key in data[1]){
                if(data[4]["google:suggesttype"][key]=="NAVIGATION"){
                suggestion+="<li><a href='"+data[1][key]+"'>"+data[2][key]+"</a> <i>("+data[4]["google:suggestrelevance"][key]+")</i></li>";
                }else{
                suggestion+="<li>"+data[1][key]+" <i>("+data[4]["google:suggestrelevance"][key]+")</i></li>";
                }
            }
            $("#suggest").html(suggestion);
        });
        $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query="+$("#search").val()+"&limit=3&encode=html&callback=?",function(data){
            var suggestion2="";
            for(var key in data.result){
                suggestion2+="<li>"+data.result[key].name+" <i>("+data.result[key].score*4+")</i></li>";
            }
            $("#suggest2").html(suggestion2);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what you're asking for. Apologies if I'm being slow. Do you want to merge the two data sets into one combined set?

Comment: @RichardMarr I can see it's a bit unclear now, sorry! Yes, that is exactly what I want to do and then order them by the values in brackets for each. Think you can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest way is to push the results from each dataset into an externally scoped variable, then sort and render from that. Example is below.

```
var combined = [],
    completed = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").keyup(function () {
        combined = [];
        completed = 0;
        $.getJSON("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q=" + $("#search").val() + "&client=chrome&callback=?", function (data) {
            for (var key in data[1]) {
                if (data[4]["google:suggesttype"][key] == "NAVIGATION") {
                    combined.push({
                        href : data[1][key],
                        text : data[2][key],
                        score : parseInt(data[4]["google:suggestrelevance"][key],10)
                    });
                } else {
                    combined.push({
                        text : data[1][key],
                        score : parseInt(data[4]["google:suggestrelevance"][key],10)
                    });
                }
            }
            if ( ++completed == 2 ) complete();
        });
        $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=" + $("#search").val() + "&limit=3&encode=html&callback=?", function (data) {
            for (var key in data.result) {
                combined.push({
                    text : data.result[key].name,
                    score : parseInt(data.result[key].score,10) * 14
                });
            }
            if ( ++completed == 2 ) complete();
        });
    });
});


function complete(){
    console.log(combined);
    combined.sort(function(a,b){ return b.score - a.score; });
    var buffer = [];
    combined.forEach(function(result){
        buffer.push("<li>"+result.text+" <i>("+result.score+")</i></li>")
    })
    $("#suggest").html(buffer.join(""));
}
```

**Edit**

This solution doesn't take into account the fact that the user may be typing at a faster pace than the APIs, that API calls may not come back in order, and doesn't do anything to try to limit the number of calls made to each API. To make this behave more consistently (and more efficiently):

- Change the keypress handler such that each key press cancels any previous timeouts then sets a new timeout at a reasonable delay (300ms seems a reasonable place to start) which then triggers the API calls
- Wrap each API call in an immediately executed function so that you can reference the value of a global counter at the time each API call was made. Increment the counter with each keypress, and don't process the response from API calls where the counter didn't match

Comment: Thanks, could you provide a demo so I could test it?

Comment: Sure, just paste it into JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rEPf3/2/  I'd also add that combining the relevance scores from different search indexes is a grey area. I assume you know what you're doing and are taking a known risk, but for those out there that don't, you can't combine relevance scores like this an expect rigorous results

Comment: Also, be aware that I changed your relevance multiplier to 14 so that you can see the intermingling

Comment: That's not your code and I tried setting it up and it wouldn't work. Could you give it a try? On your relevance point; I am going to be developing an algorithm to rank them myself so the rankings will change.

Comment: It doesn't work on keypress like my demo does. Can you fix that?

Comment: Oh, the second keypress wasn't working because the counter wasn't being cleared. Try now. http://jsfiddle.net/p3KpL/2/ In any case you should be able to see the principle from this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code for you, you have to append all the results to one container and sort in `.ajaxComplete` event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").keyup(function () {
        $("#suggest").empty();
        $.getJSON("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q=" + $("#search").val() + "&client=chrome&callback=?", function (data) {
            var suggestion = "";

            for (var key in data[1]) {
                if (data[4]["google:suggesttype"][key] == "NAVIGATION") {
                    suggestion += "<li><a href='" + data[1][key] + "'>" + data[2][key] + "</a> <i>(" + data[4]["google:suggestrelevance"][key] + ")</i></li>";
                } else {
                    suggestion += "<li>" + data[1][key] + " <i>(" + data[4]["google:suggestrelevance"][key] + ")</i></li>";
                }
            }
            $("#suggest").append(suggestion);
        });
        $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=" + $("#search").val() + "&limit=3&encode=html&callback=?", function (data) {
            var suggestion2 = "";
            for (var key in data.result) {
                suggestion2 += "<li>" + data.result[key].name + " <i>(" + data.result[key].score * 4 + ")</i></li>";
            }
            $("#suggest").append(suggestion2);

        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
            $("#suggest").html($("#suggest li").sort(function (a, b) {
                return (parseInt($(a).find("i").html(), 10) > parseInt($(b).find("i").html(), 10));

            }));
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rEPf3/8/

Comment: That isn't sorting anything currently as each API goes to it's own div and variable. How can I sort that?

Comment: @user2036031: just click the jsfiddel updated sample and search something. results are in sorted order now

Comment: this is the new url http://jsfiddle.net/rEPf3/1/ compare results in both by pressing a letter in search box

Comment: see the result for letter a in the answer, isn't that you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Add this line before to the for loop

```
data[4]["google:suggestrelevance"].sort();
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/rEPf3/5/)

**Updated**

Try combining the data sets by using a single variable

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/rEPf3/9/)

Comment: That's not ordering anything. They are exactly as it was before.

Comment: @user2036031 what type of order you want explain more

Comment: Numerical order by the values in the brackets next to each. The two data sets will need to be combined first though as explained above to Richard Marr.

Comment: @user2036031 Make clear your question. It sort with the values in the bracket

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You will need to combine the data sets into the same variable first though.

Comment: @user2036031 Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/rEPf3/9/ and try to write code from this example

Answer (score 0):

Put them together and sort.

Following is the code.
Using promise to know both ajax requests are completed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var mergedData = [];
    var promise1 = $.getJSON("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q="+$("#search").val()+"&client=chrome&callback=?",function(data){
        var suggestion="";
        console.log(data);
        var arr  = [];
        for(var i in data[1]){
        arr[i] = {value : data[1][i], rel : data[4]['google:suggestrelevance'][i]};
        }

        $.extend(mergedData,arr);

        arr.sort(function(a, b){
            return (b['rel']-a['rel']);
        });


    });
    var promise2 = $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query="+$("#search").val()+"&limit=3&encode=html&callback=?",function(data){
        console.log('data of second request', data);
        var suggestion2="";
        var arr = [];
        for(var key in data.result){
            arr[key] = {value : data.result[key].name, rel : data.result[key].score};
        }
        $.extend(mergedData,arr);
        $("#suggest2").html(suggestion2);
    });



        $.when(promise1, promise2).then(function(){
             mergedData.sort(function(a, b){
            return (b['rel']-a['rel']);
        });
            var suggestion = '';
            for(var key in mergedData){
                suggestion+='<li>' + mergedData[key].value + ' ' + mergedData[key].rel + '</li>';
            }    
            $("#suggest").html(suggestion);
        });
    });



});
```

Updated working jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rEPf3/13/

Comment: They are appearing in a completely random order. You need to merge the two data sets as explained to Richard Marr above.

Comment: Still not working. They are in the wrong order - they need to be biggest to smallest.

Comment: That is as simple as reversing the sort function.

Comment: Feels like I am talking to a tester here, it works for me even with google :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31116/discussion-between-vishwanath-and-user2036031)